# python parser find where macros are defined

Tags: python, c, macros, c-preprocessor, pyparsing

I have a test header file named header2.h that only has

```
#define ford 15
```

then another header called header1.h which defines

```
#include "myheader2.h"
#define make ford
#define car_age 10
```

I;m trying to automate a Python script using the Pyparsing library so I can parse C header files. Let's say I want to verify that the define car_age exists then I would parse header1.h and check print car_age does exist using the Python script. Let's say I want to verify that the #define make ford exists then I would have to parse header.2 to make sure "ford" exists first.

My python scripts works but my problem is that I have several header files that use definitions from other header files so the process gets very cumbersome.

I don't think the pyparsing library has a feature to help my problem. I was wondering if there is  another Python parsing library or a different tool/software that has a feature that can verify macros are defined maybe in the same header file or in another c header file like in my example? Thanks

Comment: There is an example in the pyparsing repo /examples directory to search for #defines and process the code that references them, at https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/macroExpander.py .  You can expand this example to search for "#include"s , and attach a parse action that scans that module before proceeding further in the current file (beware of accidentally scanning a cyclic include path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this design is to use parse actions to maintain the translation table for all the macros; and dynamically update the pyparsing `Forward` expression that looks for them and substitute them when they are referenced.

Starting with the macroExpander.py example, we add another expression to detect `#include`'s, a parse action to process them, and a stack to guard against cyclic includes.

```
macroInclude = "#include" + pp.quoted_string("include_file_reference").add_parse_action(pp.remove_quotes)

# global stack for include processing (to guard against cyclic includes)
include_stack = []

def process_include(s, l, t):
    filename = t.include_file_reference
    if filename in include_stack:
        raise ValueError(f"cyclic reference to {filename!r}")

    # print(f"processing file {filename!r}")
    include_stack.append(filename)

    resolved_file = resolve_file(filename)
    if resolved_file is not None:
        # searching for matches will update the macros dict
        macroExpander.search_string(resolved_file.read_text())

    # all done with this include file, pop from the stack
    include_stack.pop()
    return " ".join(t)

macroInclude.add_parse_action(process_include)
```

Add `macroInclude` to the macroExpander expression:

```
# define pattern for scanning through the input string
macroExpander = macroExpr | macroDef | macroInclude
```

I also added this line so we can comment out sample code and the parser will be smart enough to skip over them:

```
# ignore comments
macroExpander.ignore(pp.c_style_comment)
```

Here is some test code to create your sample files in a temp directory created using the tempfile module of the stdlib:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from pathlib import Path
from textwrap import dedent

# header1.h contents
file1 = dedent("""\
/* change to header1.h to see handling of cyclic include */
#include "header2.h"
#define make ford
#define car_age 10
""")

# header2.h contents
file2 = dedent("""\
#define ford 15
""")

# program.c contents
file3 = dedent("""\
#include "header1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

printf("My car is a ", make, " it is ", car_age, " years old!\\n");
""")

# create a temporary dir for header files
with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir_str:
    tmpdir = Path(tmpdir_str)

    def resolve_file(fname):
        ret = tmpdir / fname
        if ret.exists():
            return ret
        else:
            return None

    (tmpdir / "header1.h").write_text(file1)
    (tmpdir / "header2.h").write_text(file2)
    (tmpdir / "program.c").write_text(file3)

    expanded = macroExpander.transform_string((tmpdir / "program.c").read_text())
    print(expanded)
    print(macros)
```

Running this, I get the following:

```
#include header1.h
#include <stdio.h>

printf("My car is a ", 15, " it is ", 10, " years old!\n");

{'ford': '15', 'make': '15', 'car_age': '10'}
```